# Javascript - should i use inheritance model where i require a specific interface?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm in a bit of a dilemma. I am using ES6 classes for building a simple class hierarchy. One base class with a method, 3 subclasses that override that method. At some some point, i am traversing a list of instances where i call this method. Technically i don't need the class hierarchy if i can on the other hand simply guarantee that all my objects (any kind of objects) provide a method with that name. Which is the better approach?

```js
class Base {
  constructor() {

  }

  method() {
    console.log('base')
  }
}

class Subclass1 extends Base{
  constructor() {
    super()
  }

  method() {
    console.log('sc1')
  }
}

class Subclass2 extends Base{
  constructor() {
    super()
  }

  method() {
    console.log('sc2')
  }
}

class Subclass3 extends Base {
  constructor() {
    super()
  }

  method() {
    console.log('sc3')
  }
}

classInstances = [new Subclass1(), new Subclass2(), new Subclass3()];
classInstances.forEach(instance => {
  instance.method();
})

// or using any kind of objects...

obj1 = {
  method() {
    console.log('obj1');
  }
}

obj2 = {
  method() {
    console.log('obj2');
  }
}

obj3 = {
  method() {
    console.log('obj3');
  }
}
objectInstances = [obj1, obj2, obj3];
objectInstances.forEach(instance => {
  instance.method();
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, just program to the interface.

You are not using `Base.prototype.method` anywhere, it's pretty pointless - so drop it. And then `Base` is just an empty class, pretty much equivalent to `Object`, so pointless as well. You are not actually using any inheritance features here, do you don't need a class hierarchy either.

A test for `x instanceof Base` is the only use case left, but then again `typeof x.method == "function"` is much easier and more flexible.

Comment: This is a good argumentation from the usage perspective, what about class vs object (prototypical) declaration? I would argue that classes were added to JS because they make the code much more readable (and accessible to classic OOP programmers). Multiple inheritance with prototypes is very much error prone.

Comment: @U2ros You cannot do multiple inheritance anyway, so it doesn't matter for that? Apart from that, use the most simple solution - which in your example would be the plain object literals indeed. No need to make instances of anything here. No, do not use `class` syntax solely because it "makes the code more accessible to Java programmers". Yes, they make the constructor+prototype pattern much more readable, but when you don't need those then you shouldn't use `class` syntax either.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript uses 'prototypal inheritance', rather than the classical inheritance of other object orientated languages.  It's a reasonable approach to test whether an object is based on a given prototype, but given that javascript objects can be freely 'patched' to override the prototype, or even mutate the prototype, you need to be careful about what you assume about an object.

If you expect a given method to exist, then it might be more reliable to test specifically for that method, but sometimes that doesn't read so well in code.

One problem you'll encounter is creating 'base' classes that define a type but which has no default behaviour.  For example, here we could create a base type for `Animal` or `Speakable`, but the `speak` method would need to be a no-op or throw an error if ever called.  That might of course be useful during development for catching when you fail to define an expected behaviour.

Also, Javascript doesn't allow multiple inheritance, so you can't implement 'interfaces' as you might in other languages, although you can create composite prototypes that achieve a similar result.

```js
class Thing {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name
  }
}

class Dog extends Thing {
  speak() {
    return 'woof';
  }
}

class Cat extends Thing {
  speak() {
    return 'meow';
  }
}

class House extends Thing {
}

const things = [new Dog('Rover'), new Cat('Tibbles'), new House('Foo Hall')];

things.forEach(thing => {
  if (typeof thing.speak === 'function') {
    console.log(`${thing.name} says '${thing.speak()}'`);
  } else {
    console.log(`${thing.name} cannot speak`);
  }
});
```

Comment: You might want to notice that JS is not the only language that uses prototypical inheritance, there are others as well (some of them much more object-oriented than, say, Java). It's just the most popular prototype-based language.